# How to handle in app update Immediate mode when user clicks on close button?

Tags: android

As per documentation , for in app update API implementation I am using immediate mode. But there is close button on full screen UI. When user clicks on the close button, UI is dismissed. How to handle this immediate flow in this case as I don't want user to use my app?

Comment: @Manganesh DId u find anything to solve this?  Same problem here. I want mandatory update

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (listener != null) {
        appUpdateManager.registerListener(listener)
    }
    appUpdateManager
        .appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
            ) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    100
                )
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS
            ) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    100
                );
            }
        }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RESULT_OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RESULT_CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            }
            ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this should solve the problem (specifically the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` block, but what if you want to close the app ONLY for immediate updates?  How do we know if it was a flexible update or immediate update in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: What about system back button? Will  Activity.RESULT_CANCELED be called when a user clicks on the system back button?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to disallow the users to use your app until they update the app?

To do that, you can listen to update status and if the user cancels, you can request to start the update again (maybe show a dialog/message to the user explaining why the update is necessary).

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#status-callback)

> #### Get a callback for update status
>
> After starting an update, you can use an [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%2520int,%2520android.content.Intent)) callback to handle an update failure or cancellation, as shown below.
>
> ```java
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>   if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
>     if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
>       log("Update flow failed! Result code: " + resultCode);
>       // If the update is cancelled or fails,
>       // you can request to start the update again.
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Dear Vinay, In case of user closes or press close button.. this if condition is not getting called.

Comment: @Vinay No. Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

In case if user clicks on close button, you can get that callback in this condition **resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED**:-

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): Boolean {
    // React to activity result and if request code == ResultActivity.REQUEST_CODE
    if (requestCode == UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        //when user clicks update button
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "App download starts...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //if user click on close button
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "App download canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           //Here you can do whatever you want (call finish() to close the app.)
        } else if (resultCode == ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "App download failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```